# LINQ Generic Join and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics, join

My requirement is to implement a Generic Join method which would IQueryable Join .

I have used the Join method as shown below :

```
public static IQueryable Join(this IQueryable outer, IEnumerable inner, string outerSelector, string innerSelector, string resultsSelector, params object[] values)
    {
        if (inner == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("inner");
        if (outerSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("outerSelector");
        if (innerSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("innerSelector");
        if (resultsSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultsSelctor");

        System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression outerSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(outer.ElementType, null, outerSelector, values);
        System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression innerSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(inner.AsQueryable().ElementType, null, innerSelector, values);

        System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[] parameters = new System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[] {
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(outer.ElementType, "outer"), System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(inner.AsQueryable().ElementType, "inner") };
        System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression resultsSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(parameters, null, resultsSelector, values);

        return outer.Provider.CreateQuery(
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Join",
                new Type[] 
                { 
                    outer.ElementType, 
                    inner.AsQueryable().ElementType, 
                    outerSelectorLambda.Body.Type, 

                    resultsSelectorLambda.Body.Type 
                },
                outer.Expression, 
                inner.AsQueryable().Expression, 
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Quote(outerSelectorLambda), 
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Quote(innerSelectorLambda), 
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Quote(resultsSelectorLambda)));
    }


    //The generic overload.
    public static IQueryable<T> Join<T>(this IQueryable<T> outer, IEnumerable<T> inner, string outerSelector, string innerSelector, string resultsSelector, params object[] values)
    {
        return (IQueryable<T>)Join((IQueryable)outer, (IEnumerable)inner, outerSelector, innerSelector, resultsSelector, values);
    }
```

I have used the Join method as shown below :

```
       var q = Join(e1, e2, "Company_ID", "Company_ID",
        "new ( outer.Company_ID as CompanyId)"      );
```

But i get the error as shown below :

No generic method 'Join' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Please Help .

Comment: Try `IQueryable` rather than `Queryable` to start with.

Comment: That does not work as well . The error is  No method 'Join' exists on type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'.

Comment: Are you missing a `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: not sure if it really helps or not, but might look at LinqKit @ http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Comment: Check the types for the outerSelectorLambda and innerSelectorLambda expressions (i.e. Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> and Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>>) and make sure the types for TKey match.  Make sure the TInner and TOuter types match the other arguments too.

Answer (score 0):

```
outerSelectorLambda.Body.Type
```

Shouldn't this be `Body.ReturnType` ?

---

This return statement is too big.  Break it up and look at the types with the debugger.